# S3 Multipart Download on browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, javascript-objects

I have a use case where in I need to provide a file of the size of 500 MB as a downloadable to users in the browser. The file itself is stored in an S3 bucket in the backend.  As an alternate to the approach of fetching the file with a single GET S3 call, I am exploring an approach to make multiple ranged based GET calls to S3 such that the total data fetched by the ranged GET calls can be concatenated together to recreate the original file.

As the file size is on a higher side, I won’t be making all S3 ranged GET calls together such that the entire file data[from the GET call responses] is never loaded in browser memory.
Instead I plan to execute the S3 ranged GET calls in batches such that the browser memory consumed by the downloads is equal to the size of data fetched by that batch.

As a next step I am looking for a way to write the data from the GET calls batch directly to the file system [instead of maintaining them as a blob in browser memory]. The write operation should be such that data from all the batches is concatenated and stored as a single file on the user’s file system.

Are there any known ways to write data to file system in such a manner?

Comment: So just provide user with signed (or not) URL and redirect him to it. Browser will handle download

Comment: Justinas, thanks for responding. I have already considered that as an alternate approach. But am looking for ways to implement the above mentioned approach as I see improved performance overall from S3 end with ranged GET calls.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question